# What is the reason for absence of cyclone in south atlantic and south eastern pacific

Tags: tropical-cyclone

Please clarify my doubt regarding the question.It was asked in my examination.
In the South Atlantic and South-Eastern Pacific regions in tropical latitudes, cyclone does not originate. What is the reason?
(a) Sea surface temperatures are low
(b) Inter-Tropical Convergence Zone seldom occurs
(c) Coriolis force is too weak
(d) Absence of land in those regions

Comment: I think this gives a pretty good explanation of why they don't form in certain locations:    http://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/IOTD/view.php?id=7079